# How to Export Data From TitanDB to MySQL C# or By Interconnect or Passthru

Tags: c#, mysql, database, titan

We have a client that has a TitanDB a graphing database, we have a MySQL database that will need to receive data from Titan and possibly in the future return data to Titan. 
1: I have never worked with TitanDB so I am looking for how do I get data from it into MySQL, either via C#, PassThrough Connection or some other means. 
The data would not be huge swaths - but many small chunks less than 10,000 records at a time and roughly once or twice a day.

Could someone provide some concise relevant information on how exactly to go about accomplishing this task ?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like you are asking how to migrate data from a MySQL database to TitanDB. Unfortunately at this moment there is no automated way to do this.

The structure of a graph database is very different from that of a RDBMS. For example, with MySQL you query your data but with Titan (and the [Tinkerpop API](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) it implements) you traverse your data.

If you are willing to write your own migration protocol then you can make use of [Titans](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html) REST API. That way you can write it in C# or whatever you want. More details on talking to the server can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_rest).

Myself and some colleagues have built a knowledge graph, [Grakn](https://grakn.ai/) on top of Titan. This does include migration support so if you curious you can try us out [here](https://grakn.ai/).

Comment: I am not trying to migrate the data (I just need a certain amount of data each day - working list of production data) - however migrating Titan might be something that is done in the future as the client has expressed a desire to replace Titan.  I will have a look at both of your links.

Comment: I got your problem literally the wrong way around :) . Unfortunately the answer is still a "no automated way sadly". You could walk thorough the graph using the REST API though. With the correct Traversals you could control how you walk through the graph and thereby control the amount of data you dealing with each time.

Comment: I think I will look definitely into the REST API , my experience with graphing dbs is about 1 week (so I lack alot). I am not sure why my client is even using this database as from what it looks like to me is more for determining the relationships of data and not really for persistence and job control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mizo](https://github.com/imri/mizo) - it is an implementation of Spark RDD for Titan on HBase, that bypasses HBase main API, and parses HBase [internal data files](http://Apache%20HBase%20I/O%20-%20HFile%20-%20Cloudera%20Engineering%20Blog) (called HFiles).

I have tested it on a pretty large scale -- a Titan graph with hundreds of billions of elements, weighing about 25TB.

Because it does not rely on the Scan API that HBase exposes, it is much faster. For example, counting edges in the graph I mentioned takes about **10 hours** using 100 Spark cores.

Comment: I will have a look at this to see what I need to do.